# VBA Loop through Directory - Store Results & Sort - Use Array?

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

I'm trying to write some VBA code (will run in Outlook) that will loop through a directory and return the file path and last modified date for files that meet a certain criteria. I have limited experience and have not used arrays at all.

Not sure if its the best approach but the test code below does output the file path and date that I need.

```
        Sub LoopFiles()

        Dim strFolder As String
        Dim strFile As String
        Dim strDirRef As String

        strFolder = "C:\Users\T400\Documents\MacroCROtest\"
        strFile = "*Test*"    ''''criteria / partial file name
        strDirRef = Dir(strFolder & strFile)

    Do While Len(strDirRef) > 0

    Debug.Print FileDateTime(strFolder & strDirRef) & " " & strFolder & strDirRef
'> OUTPUT = 5/23/16 10:25:59 AM   C:\Users\T400\Documents\MacroCROtest\TEST 1.pdf

        strDirRef = Dir

        Loop

        End Sub
```

I now need a way to store the results -- which will then need to be sorted by date. I'm only expecting 4-5 files to be selected when the code is run and not sure if should (need?) to store these in an array or if could just be stored in a series of strings. I have tried to work out how to assign the returned data to strings with variations of code shown below -- but cannot get to work.

```
Do While Len(strDirRef) > 0 
  i = i + 1  
strFound(i) = strDirRef
```

How do I store and sort the returned data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as for the storing see these two different options

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopFiles()

Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strDirRef As String
Dim nFiles As Long, i As Long
Dim strFound() As String

strFolder = "C:\Users\T400\Documents\MacroCROtest\"
strFile = "*Test*"    ''''criteria / partial file name

strDirRef = Dir(strFolder & strFile)    
Do While Len(strDirRef) > 0    
    nFiles = nFiles + 1
    ReDim Preserve strFound(1 To nFiles)
    strFound(nFiles) = strDirRef
    strDirRef = Dir
Loop

For i = 1 To nFiles
    MsgBox strFound(i)
Next i    

End Sub

Sub LoopFiles2()

Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strDirRef As String
Dim nFiles As Long
Dim strFoundStr As String
Dim strFoundArr As Variant
Dim strElem As Variant

strFolder = "C:\Users\T400\Documents\MacroCROtest\"
strFile = "*Test*"    ''''criteria / partial file name

strDirRef = Dir(strFolder & strFile)    
Do While Len(strDirRef) > 0

    strFoundStr = strFoundStr & strDirRef & " "
    strDirRef = Dir

Loop

strFoundArr = Split(Trim(strFoundStr)) '<~~ use Split() function to return an array fo strings

For Each strElem In strFoundArr
    MsgBox strElem
Next strElem

End Sub
```

while as for sorting arrays, well there's plenty of code out there: just google it

Comment: Appreciate the quick response - both options are working & I will work to fully understand both. I also had a question about the first option. It returns all files as expected for `strFound(i)`, but if I ask for a specific file like `strFound (2)` it returns the 2nd file found n-Times. I thought would only return it once. Is that how it should function or does it depend on how its being used?

Comment: Please disregard the above question - works as expected when request for a specific item is outside the For Next loop.